# SQL Server dynamic crosstb query with where parameter

Tags: sql-server

In below dynamic query I get this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@κωδ_κατηγ2"

when set `WHERE (κωδ_κατηγ = @κωδ_κατηγ2)` in the `@query`.

If set `WHERE (κωδ_κατηγ = 1)` works fine.

How can I dissolve this error?

How to pass value from the `ControlParameter` @κωδ_κατηγ2 to `@query`?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="apotelesmata_diast_db" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:epsa_mssql %>'
     SelectCommand="DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)                

  SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Ομάδα1) FROM ( SELECT κωδ_κατηγ, Ομάδα1 FROM [2014_2015].[αποτελεσματα_ερ2] ) d  
            WHERE (κωδ_κατηγ = @κωδ_κατηγ1) GROUP BY κωδ_κατηγ, Ομάδα1 ORDER BY Ομάδα1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 

  SET @query = 'SELECT Ομάδα2,' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (select κωδ_κατηγ, Ομάδα1, Ομάδα2, Σκορ
            from [2014_2015].[αποτελεσματα_ερ2] pd 
            WHERE (κωδ_κατηγ = @κωδ_κατηγ2)
            GROUP BY κωδ_κατηγ, Ομάδα1, Ομάδα2, Σκορ) x             
        pivot 
        (max(Σκορ) for Ομάδα1 in (' + @cols + ')) p '                 
            EXEC sp_executesql @query;">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="katigoties_ddl" 
              PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="κωδ_κατηγ1" Type="Int16">
         </asp:ControlParameter>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="katigoties_ddl" 
              PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="κωδ_κατηγ2" Type="Int16">
         </asp:ControlParameter>                    
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
'WHERE (κωδ_κατηγ = @κωδ_κατηγ2)'
```

On this:

```
'WHERE (κωδ_κατηγ = ' + CAST(@κωδ_κατηγ2 as nvarchar(10)) + ')'
```

The error occurs when executing dynamic query. It cant get a variable which is not part of dynamic query.

Comment: Great it helps! Please, be free to accept/upvote answers that helps you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameters to a dynamic query using paramdef

```
declare @paramdef nvarchar(max) = N'@κωδ_κατηγ2 int, @κωδ_κατηγ1 int';
EXEC sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @κωδ_κατηγ1=@κωδ_κατηγ1, @κωδ_κατηγ2=@κωδ_κατηγ2;
```